# grub> unable to locate kernel or boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I made an attempt to follow procedures at LFS to build a linux system and somewhere along the way i messed up my dual boot or grub setup.

I made a new partition (/dev/sda8).
Tried to mount the partition and mkdir(s), but the operations failed.
I then added the partition to the /etc/fstab file.
Commands still would not execute, I obviously had done something wrong.
I deleted the partition with fdisk.
I removed the entry from /etc/fstab.
After rebooting, windows booted without an option for ubuntu mate.
Pressing "esc" shows ubuntu and windows, but selecting ubuntu provides only a grub> prompt.
Going through the motions in grub, gets me nowhere.  It is unable to recognize the file system my ubuntu install is on (/dev/sda7) and is unable to locate vmlinuzx.x.x.
Am I looking at a complete reinstall or is this salvageable?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downloading "grub boot repair" and flashing the ISO to a usb drive.
Following the on screen prompts allowed me to boot into ubuntu-mate.
I have to "esc" into the boot menu to select "ubuntu" from a massive new grub list, or else it boots straight to windows.
I'll take it.